# Javascript difference between store the function into variable with function name or without function name?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two functions;

```
 var a = function () { console.log("hi");  }  
 var b = function xyz() { console.log("hi");  }
```

When i call these two functions both are giving same result. Then what is point in declaring function name 'xyz' ?

Comment: 'a' is an anonymous function while you are assigning to 'b' a function called xyz

Answer (score 0):

The second form is called a "named function expression". It gives you several benefits over normal function expressions:

- It makes it a bit easier to debug -- when you have a bunch of functions like those, and you get an error, naming your functions makes it a bit easier to interpret the resulting stack trace.
- You can call named functions recursively -- for example, doing:

  ```
  f = function f() {
      f();
  };

  f();
  ```

  ...works.

You can find more detailed information [here](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/#feature-of-named-function-expression-nfe).

Using named function expressions also comes with some disadvantages. <s>For example, doing `f = function g() { ... }` will actually create *two* entities -- the functions `f` and `g`, which can potentially be confusing.</s> (see comments)  There are also some intricacies with scoping which can potentially cause bugs if you're not careful. You can find more detailed information [here](http://kiro.me/blog/nfe_dilemma.html).

Comment: The expression `f = function g() {...}` no longer appears to "leak" g into the enclosing namespace. That post was written in 2012 and I believe some updates were made regarding that. I played around with some of his code here: http://jsfiddle.net/shashank92/uk7buehf/

Comment: Yeah, creating two instances was only a bug in older IE versions.

Comment: `var test = function (){ 

      console.log(1);
      test();
   }
test();`

This one also recursive....